# How to make Gmail the default handler for email on a Windows PC?

Tags: gmail

I am using the Snippet Screen Capture application on Windows 7 and when I use the `email to` option it defaults to Exchange.

How can I change this to default to Gmail?

Comment: I know it's possible, because I've done it at home.  There may be limitations though (like only mailto links within Firefox).

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. The solution linked to works only for MailTo: links within the browser. My question was specifically about a Windows program (Snippet Screen capture tool) which defaults to Exchange. I want it to default to Gmail.

Comment: [TVHGoogleMapi](http://jankeirse.github.io/tvhgooglemapi/) does the job, see also linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this suggestion from a [Channel9 thread on this topic](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/252967-Email-in-Gmail-Explorer-Context-menu) -

> I installed this for someone not so long ago when I rebuilt their
>   laptop. (save as .reg)
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\GMail]
> @="GMail"
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\GMail\shell]
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\GMail\shell\open]
> @="GMail"
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\GMail\shell\open\command]
> @="rundll32.exe url.dll,FileProtocolHandler http://www.gmail.com"
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\GMail\DefaultIcon]
> @="C:\\WINDOWS\\gmail.ico"
> ```
>
> (and put the gmail favicon in c:\windows then change your email
>   provider in Set Program Access and Defaults

[LifeHacker recommends](http://lifehacker.com/5177419/how-do-i-attach-a-file-in-gmail-from-the-windows-context-menu) using an application called [Affixa](http://lifehacker.com/5141411/affixa-integrates-gmail-others-with-your-desktop-for-easy-file-attachment) which registers itself as the default email application on your computer and handles file uploading to Gmail.

Comment: The Registry change did NOT fix it. But Affixa did.

Answer (score 0):

My Blog Article might help (http://www.lauramartin.co.nz/how-to-set-your-automatic-mailto-to-use-gmail-instead-of-outlook-in-google-chrome/).
You can change your default email client easily enough using Chrome Settings or the Plugin.
Hope it helps.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include the details in the answer itself instead of posting links.

Comment: External links can disappear or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please edit your answer to include the gist of the link to make your answer self-contained.